# How can I make lookup on in with productId and categoryId

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

How can make I lookup on in with productId and categoryId.

Below is the sample of JSON

```json
  "data": {
        "status": 1,
        "offerId": "634017ad34c7b3545bd47681",
        "offerType": "buyOneGetOne",
        "categoryId": [
            "62de9b22dcafd44290ab03c1",
            "62dfe695ec4d69cfeab0265d"
        ],
        "productId": [
            "633170230e88e2d859d15ee6",
            "62de9d102b2b72f80eda7585",
            "62de9d1e2b2b72f80eda7588"
        ],
        "title": "Buy One Get One Deal ",
        "description": "buy one get more",
        "amountType": "amount",
        "amount": 12341,
        "startDate": "2022-10-04T06:43:39.000Z",
        "endDate": "2022-10-08T06:43:39.000Z"
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The answer to the question in the title is probably "yes", but we're going to need more information to say for sure.  Please edit your question to provide [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) sample documents, details about which field(s) are relevant, and other information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are using `ObjectId` as `_id` in your `categories` and `products` collection. If I understood your question your document as the following minimal structure:

```json
_id: '1',
data: {
...
}
```

So, you are looking for something like:

```js
db.nameOfYourCollectionWithData.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        'data.categoryId': {
            $map: {
                input: '$data.categoryId',
                'in': {
                    $toObjectId: '$$this'
                }
            }
        },
        'data.productId': {
            $map: {
                input: '$data.productId',
                'in': {
                    $toObjectId: '$$this'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'categories',
        localField: 'data.categoryId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'data.categoryId'
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'products',
        localField: 'data.productId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'data.productId'
    }
}])
```

First, you have to convert your array ids into `ObjectId`. After do this, you can perform the `lookup` stages directly. If your document is 'data', just remove any reference to `data` in the aggregate pipeline.
If your `_id` in categories and products are string instead of `ObjectId`, just remove the `$addFields` stage, because is no longer neccessary.